# How to Replace an element with another element entirely with data and events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have cloned an element like this

```
var myVar = null;
myVar = $(someOtherVar).clone(true, true)
```

Now I want to replace `anotherVar` entirely with `myVar`. How to do that?

I tried `$(anotherVar).replaceWith(myVar)` But that doesn't work. Any other way to replace `anotherVar` entirely with data and events of `myVar`?

Comment: you have the right idea. Here is a working fiddle for you to check your logic: http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/suCEe/1/ Can you explain what's happening or not happening in your case? Note that "id" values get cloned so you have to manually change the cloned ids or use classes instead.

Comment: Actually in my case the `jQuery data` and `events` are not copied! and trying your suggestion I loss that element also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Since you want two references:

```
var myVar = $(someOtherVar).clone(true, true);
var anotherVar = $(myVar).clone(true, true);;
```

If you need two clones, you have to clone twice. There's no way around it.

Comment: What is `$(myVar).hide();` line?
And should I again deep clone to `anotherVar` to copy `myVar` to `anotherVar`?

Comment: But I want value-by-value cloning. As I have said all the events, data and properties and `innerHTML` etc. should be copied to `someOtherVar` to `anotherVar` via `myVar`.

Comment: And using your example `myVar` is not retaining its value also.

Comment: How to apply `jQuery.fn.init`?

Comment: It's getting complex. Can you congregate your solution to one place please?

Comment: Is it value-by-value copy? with data and events copy also?

Comment: Though the value are copied. While I am debugging, I can see that value is changed. But Then after the function is passed, the HTML is not changed!